# Couchbase indexer is eating all the memory

Tags: couchbase

Couchbase indexer is eating all the memory, even when configure to 4 gig mem limit. The db is not in use by any app, just reboot the machine with running couchbase with 150 million docs. Index build progress is 100%.

Server is Community Edition 5.1.1 build 5723.

[image: Configured in the ui for 4 giga]

And also manually:

curl -X POST -u Administrator:password 
http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default 
-d ‘indexMemoryQuota=4000’

After reboot, or after the manually command, the memory is cleared, but then back to grow, after 2 hours, its on 24% from total of 64 gig, that's 15 gig and growing.. it will not stop until memory is full.

[image: Memory consumption]

Any idea how to configure its properly?

Thanks,
Ady.

Comment: Indexer service now on 43% and growing.

Comment: Now its on 18.5%?
This maybe compaction? but I set indexer limit it to 4 giga, twice.

Comment: Back to grow... 22%

Comment: It looks like there are a couple of bugs still open for this issue you might want to keep an eye on: https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-19883 and https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-19895

Comment: Those bugs are from 2016, version 4.5.0. We are 2 years later, with version 5.1.1. And this is a critical bug, not just a minor one, we can't work. In the time we speak, 2 hours after my previous comment, the indexer already on 32%. Unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

can you please run the below when you see high memory usage and share the output files.

`curl http://<host>:9102/debug/pprof/heap -u <username>:<password> > indexer.mprof`

`curl http://<host>:9102/debug/pprof/goroutine?debug=1 -u <username:password> > indexer.gr`

Once you have captured the above information, you can try applying the below settings, restart indexer and see if that helps the system behavior:

`curl -X POST -u <user:pass> http://<ip>:9102/settings --data '{"indexer.dataport.dataChanSize": 1000}'`

`curl -X POST -u <user:pass> http://<ip>:9102/settings --data '{"indexer.stream_reader.fdb.workerBuffer": 1000}'`

`curl -X POST -u <user:pass> http://<ip>:9102/settings --data '{"indexer.stream_reader.fdb.mutationBuffer": 1000}'`

Comment: Its now on 45% of the memory. almost 30 gig instead of 4. Here are the files: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19aGSkzH8vbe5OQn2JueGiMovYDfmESZk  
I ran the commands, got ok on all, restarted the machine.
I will update soon.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Didn't help. Indexer now on 10% and growing... (6.4 gig instead of 4 gig limit)

Comment: From the memory profile, the memory usage is coming from the storage engine. There are not enough granular stats in community storage engine to get more details. It looks like the earlier crashes may have caused the storage to go in a bad state. You can try to drop/recreate the indexes.

Also, as the total indexed data for 4 indexes is around 160GB, it would be good to have indexer RAM quota to be 10GB. That should help it to function better.

Comment: Delete all indexes. No indexes - at all.
Restarted machine.
Waited 2 hours to see memory print, 0.5% - good.

Trying to create one index again and I am getting:
“msg”: “GSI CreateIndex() - cause: Encounter errors during create index. Error=Indexer In Recovery\n.”

Comment: Thanks for sharing the logs. I see that 3 out of 4 indexes were dropped before the restart. The last index got dropped after the restart. Though it is not a problem to do that, unfortunately, the system run into a rare race condition. I have filed a ticket to address the underlying problem.

https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-31592

Meanwhile, you’ll need to kill the indexer process to get it out of this state and you should be able to start creating indexes again.